# Select sublist where each element has a 1.5% chance to be included

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, sublist

```
     tmp = []
     while len(tmp) == 0:
         for i in range(0,385):
             # Multiplying by 100 in order to remove the decimal point
             if randint(0,10000) < chance*100:
                 tmp.append(i)
     return tmp
```

This is the code I'm currently using to help clear things up. The output will be something like this.

```
[34, 234, 243, 321]
```

My current solution is very inefficient. I tried this:

```
sample(range(0,385), math.ceil(chance*3.85))
```

But it doesn't produce the same effect. Also if you could tell me the name of what this is called that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

n = 385
chance = 0.015  # Chance of 1.5%
main_list = np.arange(n)  # Generate initial list
rnd = np.random.uniform(size=main_list.shape)  # Generate random number between 0 and 1

sublist = main_list[rnd < chance]  # Select numbers
```

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for!